# How to disallow the copy constructor and use only move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

In following scenario ( its just a *sscce* ), how can I avoid copy constructor (the commented out code ) ?

```
typedef boost::variant< std::vector<int>, 
                        std::vector<char>, 
                        std::vector<float> 
                       > VecRMPType;

struct Widgets{
    int widget_id;
    VecRMPType rmps_vec ;

    template< typename T>
    Widgets(int wid, T rmps_vec_ ) : 
    widget_id(wid), rmps_vec( std::move(rmps_vec_) ) 
    {
    }

    Widgets( const Widgets&& wids_ ) :
    widget_id( wids_.widget_id), rmps_vec(wids_.rmps_vec )
    {
    }
    /*
    // This constructor I want to disable.
    Widgets( const Widgets& wids_ ):
    widget_id( wids_.widget_id), rmps_vec( std::move(wids_.rmps_vec) )
    {
    }
    */
};

class Layers {

    int symb_id;
    std::vector< Widgets > widgets ;

    Layers(const Layers& ) ;
    Layers& operator=(const Layers& ) ;

    public:
        Layers(int sid_, std::vector<Widgets> wids_ ):
        symb_id(sid_), widgets(std::move(wids_) )
        { }

        Layers(const Layers&& L_ ): 
        symb_id(L_.symb_id), widgets( std::move(L_.widgets) )
        { }
 };
```

---

Currently, compiler throws an [*error*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e31213ed933702a)

Am I missing something obvious or have any misconception(s) ?

<sup>PS: I tried searching on related thing on SO, but still not able to find one, if its duplicate, please comment, and I'll delete the question.</sup>

Comment: You can't move from const rvalue references, get rid of the const from your move constructor arguments. Then you must `std::move` each data member in the initializer list.

Comment: According to the error, the copy constructor is "disabled" (as expected). So what are you actually asking?

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry my bad, following the suggestions I got it working without copy constructor, I just wanted to avoid deep copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move constructors usually look like:

```
Foo(Foo&& other)
```

You must also explicitly use `std::move` on the components.

Then, `delete` the copy constructors:

```
Foo(Foo const&) = delete;
```

although simply omitting them is also acceptable if you have a user provided move constructor.